# Using backportpackage gives circular-ish dependency

Tags: 16.04, launchpad, backport

I'm trying to use `backportpackage` to backport `htop`. The build fails because it needs `debhelper (>= 11)`. When I tried to backport `debhelper` it failed because it needs `dpkg-dev (>= 1.19.0.5~)`. When I tried to backport `dpkg` it failed because it needs `debhelper (>= 10)`.

I'm thinking/hoping I'm not using this tool correctly, but I'm not sure what I need to do get all the dependencies met.

The command I used:
`backportpackage -u ppa:backports4/backports htop -w htop`

These are the builds:

htop https://launchpad.net/~backports4/+archive/ubuntu/backports/+build/14492474 
debhelper https://launchpad.net/~backports4/+archive/ubuntu/backports/+build/14492505 
dpkg https://launchpad.net/~backports4/+archive/ubuntu/backports/+build/14492508

Comment: As someone who runs into this problem regularly, edit the package's source code to use an older debhelper comparison string.  This may require you to download the package completely and then modify it to make it work.  `dpkg` and `debhelper` are **nearly impossible** to backport safely without really knowing that set of packages.

Comment: @ThomasWard If I add the PPA of someone who has already backported `dpkg` and `debhelper`, will that be automatically picked up and used by `backportpackage`?

Comment: possibly but I doubt it.  Those are packages that are so painful to backport because you tend to break the packaging system with those special case upgrades.  You are better off just tweaking the package deps for the package being built (I can do that if you really need it...)